# The --unstable flag must be provided

Tags: deno

I am facing this error while running the **Deno** program.

So can anyone help me **how to add multiple flags in Deno?**

This is My Code: **index.ts**

```
import * as bcrypt from "https://deno.land/x/bcrypt/mod.ts";

const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(8);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash("test", salt);
console.log(hash);
```

and command I am using for same:

```
deno run --allow-net index.ts
```

I am new on Deno

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can chain as many flags as you want after `run` and before the script.

```
deno run --flag1 --flag2 --flagN script.ts
```

So you should do:

```
deno run --allow-net --unstable index.ts
```